# Using XPATH to get child nodes having index divisible by n

Tags: xpath

My XML is some how like this:

```
<a>
    <b></b> <!-- 1 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 2 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 3 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 4 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 5 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 6 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 7 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 8 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 9 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 10 -->
    <b></b> <!-- 11 -->
</a>
```

Is the a way to write XPATH that get child nodes of **a** having index divisible by **n**? For example, with **n** = 3, it will get **b** nodes with index 3, 6, 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> get child nodes of **a** having index divisible by **n**

Like this:

```
/a/*[position() mod 3 = 0]
```

Note that `position()` returns a 1-based index.